# jquery ui button padding override

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, button

HTML markup is as follows:

```
<button id="Refresh"><img src="refresh.png" /></button>
```

I am creating this button as a jquery ui button with the following code:

```
$("#Refresh").button();
```

Calling this function produces the following markup:

```
<button id="Refresh" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-button-text">
        <img src="refresh.png">
    </span>
</button>
```

This works fine. The result is a button with padding of `.4em 1em;` as defined in jquery's CSS. (`.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text`)

I have several buttons on this page, and I like this padding for most of them. However, for this one button in particular I'd like to have no padding. I realize I could just change the CSS for `.ui-button-text-only` and  `.ui-button-text` but that would screw up the other buttons using this style, and I like them the way they are.

So I'm wondering if there's any way to override this css **just for one button**. I took a look at [jquery's button docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/) but it doesn't appear to allow passing of specific CSS in with the button options.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you tried adding a class after the button is created?

Comment: @JoshMein do you mean trying to override jquery's css class? If so, wouldn't that just override the css for the other buttons as well?

Comment: I meant to add a class to that specific button. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add a new class to the span within the button after it is created.

```
$("#Refresh").button();
$("#Refresh").find('span.ui-button-text').addClass('yourClass');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply style it using CSS. To make sure it's not overridden add '!important'

Add the span tag

```
#Refresh span {
    padding:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. My guess is because it's not actually #Refresh being styled, but the span jquery creates.

Comment: use a selector like `button#Refresh span.ui-button-text` and it will work as intended.

Comment: to access the jquery button, don't forget the prefix "ui-", .ui-button.clearButton span.ui-button-text{padding:0;} // here I also created a class clearButton as per accepted answer